# Applescript to capture result of close dialog

Tags: dialog, applescript

How does one capture a "Don't Save" or "Save" response to the Standard Suite "close" dialog?

```
    try
        close front document saving ask
    on error
        return
    end try
```

returns "error number -10000" if the user selects "Cancel", so that case is handled.

However, subsequent code depends on whether  "Don't Save" or "Save" was selected.

Thanks

---

**UPDATE**

Using regulus's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12804523/261305) and it's workaround strategy, I prefaced the code above with

```
tell application "Finder" to set _modDateAfterSaveDialog to 
modification date of (info for file _filename)
```

where the _filename was assigned earlier from application-specific AS code.

Analogous code and a test followed the "try".

Comment: Please accept regulus6633 answer if it solved your question. So others can see it has been solved without having to click into the question. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really have no idea how to get it directly. I assume the command you are issuing is a specific application command, not a standard suite command because standard applescript doesn't have a "front document".

In any case, here's a work-around idea that might work. When a file is saved its modification date changes. So you need to know the file of the front document. Then you just check the modification date of the file before and after you issue this command. If it changed then you know the file was saved.

Good luck.